# base class with abstract method returning T

Tags: c#

I am defining a base class that has a method that returns type T. The classes the derive from this can return different types.

```
public abstract class BaseTransport
{
    public abstract T Properties<T>();
}

public class Car : BaseTransport
{
    public override T Properties<T>()
    {
       return new CarProperties();
    }
}

public class Bike : BaseTransport
{
    public override T Properties<T>()
    {
       return new BikeProperties();
    }
}
```

If it makes a difference the return BikeProperties and CarProperties are both derived from BaseProperties.

Is this possible to do? Just trying to enforce the implementation of a method...

Comment: What if somebody calls `car.Properties<String>();`?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, Generic doesn't quite work this way.  Without an example of what is using `Car` and `Bike` it's not really possible to answer this question.

Comment: It doesn't help that you've renamed the type parameter in `Car` and `Bike` as well. C# is case-sensitive: `t` and `T` are entirely different identifiers. It sounds like you need to make the *class* generic rather than making the *method* generic though.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry, t should have been T, it has been edited by Erik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want generic methods, you want a generic class:

```
public abstract class BaseTransport<T> where T : BaseProperties
{
    public abstract T Properties();
}

public class Car : BaseTransport<CarProperties>
{
    public override CarProperties Properties()
    {
       return new CarProperties();
    }
}

public class Bike : BaseTransport<BikeProperties>
{
    public override BikeProperties Properties()
    {
       return new BikeProperties();
    }
}
```

Comment: I will look at this after I look at Links response. The properties is just one of the differences, and your example works well with properties but more complex examples will probably come down the pipeline.

Comment: @ginalster It sounds like you have an X-Y problem here.

Comment: public abstract class BaseTransport<T> where T:BaseProperties is even better.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thx